# CLion CMake ld: library not found + Vulkan and OpenGL questions

Tags: c++, opengl, cmake, glfw, vulkan

I am trying to get a basic setup with GLFW and Vulkan for an upcoming project. I was trying to get a simple HelloTriangle Example to work. While the Vulkan library is building normally, the GLFW is throwing a `ld: library not found for -lglfw3` on running the program. I am also unsure whether my HelloTriangle example is a working example; it was the most basic example I have to seen to test Vulkan.
Here is my CMakeList.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(OpenGLRun)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(glfw3_DIR /usr/local/Cellar/glfw/3.3.2/lib/cmake/glfw3)

add_executable(OpenGLRun main.cpp)

find_package(vulkan REQUIRED)
find_package(glm REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_package(glfw3 REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries(OpenGLRun Vulkan::Vulkan)
target_link_libraries(OpenGLRun glm)
target_link_libraries(OpenGLRun OpenGL::GL)
target_link_libraries(OpenGLRun glfw3)
```

And the main.cpp example code that I was trying to run for proof that everything was working:

```
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_VULKAN
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cstdlib>

const uint32_t WIDTH = 800;
const uint32_t HEIGHT = 600;

class HelloTriangleApplication {
public:
    void run() {
        initWindow();
        initVulkan();
        mainLoop();
        cleanup();
    }

    private:

        GLFWwindow* window;

        void initWindow() {
            glfwInit();

            glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_NO_API);
            glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_FALSE);

            GLFWwindow *window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Vulkan", nullptr, nullptr);
        }

private:
    void initVulkan() {

    }

    void mainLoop() {
        while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
            glfwPollEvents();
        }
    }

    void cleanup() {
        glfwDestroyWindow(window);

        glfwTerminate();
    }
};

int main() {
    HelloTriangleApplication app;

    try {
        app.run();
    } catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

And finally, for the future, would you recommend package managers in C++/CMake?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You might try linking to just `glfw` instead, as suggested on [their site](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/build_guide.html).

Comment: @BDL Yeah, I will ask another question for that one, thanks

Comment: @squarekittles But when I remove the linking and finding of GLFW from the CMake lists I get this error (just including the GLFW from main.cpp) ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Comment: Sorry, I meant only change one line in your CMake. Change this `target_link_libraries(OpenGLRun glfw3)` to this: `target_link_libraries(OpenGLRun glfw)`

Comment: Wow, that worked, thank you for all your help =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GLFW [Build Guide](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/build_guide.html#build_link_cmake_source) suggests that whether you are compiling and linking GLFW along with your application, or linking an *installed* GLFW to your application, you can **link** GLFW to your application using the `glfw` target (not `glfw3`). Change the [`target_link_libraries()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html) command in your CMake to this:

```
target_link_libraries(OpenGLRun PRIVATE glfw)
```

Note, you should *always* provide the scoping argument when using the target-based commands such as this, to tell CMake whether this is a build requirement, a usage requirement, or both.